# Flash/AS3 for videogames tools

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What are the best tools for developing videogames in Flash/ActionScript 3?

[UPDATE]
I mean tools for debugging, visualization, editing.  I'm not new to ActionScript but would like to know if there are any usual tools commonly used to optimize workflow.
I'm looking for tools similar to what Instruments is for XCode.  Maybe something for analytics such as Localytics or something for debugging?

Comment: Hmm let me think... I would say 1) Flash, 2) ActionScript3

Comment: I mean tools for debugging, visualization, editing.  I'm not new to ActionScript but would like to know if there are any usual tools commonly used to optimize workflow.
I'm looking for tools similar to what Instruments is for XCode.

Comment: So not really for "videogames tools" then!? You should ask the question to get the answer you are looking for. Can't expect people to just guess.

Comment: Sorry about being so non-specific.  Actually that's what I want with this question: general tools for flash videogame developing in different areas of development.  Sorry again for not stating the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Flash and Actionscript (thank you Adam :), there are many resources out there that can help you, here are a few:

[Flash Gaming Engines](http://www.flashrealtime.com/flash-game-library-engine-list/)

[Game Gears](http://www.as3gamegears.com/tag/mit/)

[Some good example code of various game types](http://pelfusion.com/tutorials/35-flash-game-development-tutorials-fla-files/)

There was also another great site I used to go to a lot, but I can't think of it off the top of my head. These sites should get you started. If you are looking for more just Google what you want.

Comment: Thanks ToodBFisher.  These are indeed good links for tools on how to start.  I'm actually looking for more advanced tools for profiling and more, maybe some good libraries for professional use too.  I know a few but I have been out of Flash games for a while and am hoping to get updated on the latest innovations.

Answer (score 2):

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is my person favourite IDE, but it is more than just a ActionScript editor. It comes with a bunch of useful tools, including a profiler like Instruments for XCode. Looking around at the features should show you a lot of the latest innovations in the Flash community.

You you are looking at keeping really up to date take a look at [Flash Daily](http://flashdaily.net/) for what can be done with the latest FlashPlayer.

Comment: Flash Daily looks a very good place.  Thanks for the input.  I used to code using FlashDevelop when I had a PC.  Today I have a Mac and know that FlashDevelop does not have a native port for MacOS X.  Do you know any tool as FlashDevelop for MacOS?